# Kotlin: Starting service after BroadcastReceiver not working

Tags: android, kotlin, service, broadcastreceiver

I`m trying to build a service that detects if the screen of a device is locked/unlocked (which I will later user as a native module in React). However, it seems like my service is not starting, and I don't receive the expected logs. Where is my mistake? (It's my first time dealing with native android & Kotlin, so apologies if this is a dumb question, and duplicates were related to java code)..

I have defined a Broadcast Receiver for each event here:

**ScreenOnReceiver.kt**

```kotlin
class screenOnReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if(intent!!.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) {
            val screenOff = false
            val i = Intent(context, PowerButtonService::class.java)
            i.putExtra("screenState", screenOff)
            context!!.startService(i)
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenOffReceiver.kt**

```kotlin
class screenOffReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if(intent!!.action == Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON) {
            val screenOff = false
            val i = Intent(context, PowerButtonService::class.java)
            i.putExtra("screenState", screenOff)
            context!!.startService(i)
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenChangeService.kt**:

```kotlin
class ScreenChangeService: Service() {

    override fun onBind(p0: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
            val screenOnReceiver = screenONReceiver()
            val screenOnFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)
            registerReceiver(screenOnReceiver, screenOnFilter)

            val screenOffReceiver = screenOffReceiver()
            val screenOffFilter = IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)
            registerReceiver(screenOffreceiver, screenOffFilter)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val screenState = intent!!.getBooleanExtra("screenState", false)
        if (screenState == true) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Screen On")
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Screen Off")
        }
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```xml
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Test">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".PowerButtonService"/>
    </application>
```

Comment: You seem to have some circular logic here. Your service is started by the receivers. The receivers are started by the service. Initially, none of them are started, and so nothing will start either of them. Also note that you cannot start a service from the background on modern versions of Android.

Comment: I see. I assume the service should be started first and invoke the receivers? What is the proper way to initialize the service? My goal is to detect the screen changes while the app is running in the background which should be possible this way right?

Comment: "What is the proper way to initialize the service?" -- sorry, but I do not know how React Native handles that sort of thing. Note that it will need to be a foreground service on Android 8.0+. "My goal is to detect the screen changes while the app is running in the background" -- in principle, yes.

Comment: Thank you. How are you initializing the service in a pure android environment? I think it shouldn't make a difference if I export it as a native module to react-native

Comment: "How are you initializing the service in a pure android environment?" -- you would call `startForegroundService()` on some `Context`, with an `Intent` identifying your service implementation. However, what I do not know is where and how you would do that in the form of a React Native plugin.